# Redux Saga - dispatching action from call function

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Is there a way in `redux saga` to dispatch an action from a function that is being called by `call` effect to the global store?

for example:

```
export function* login({ payload }) {
  try {
    // from API.post I want to be able to dispatch an action that I will handle in a different saga.
    const resp = yield call(API.post, 'api/1/login', {
      email: payload.email,
      password: payload.password,
    });
   yield put(AuthActions.loginSuccess(resp.token));
 } catch (error) {
   yield put(AuthActions.loginError(error));
 }
}
```

I know that I can use saga's `channel`, but if I pass channel to the `API.post` I must use `take(channel)` and I want to handle this action in a different file so I dont have access to this channel. And I also not sure I want to export the channel and import it in a different file cause I want each saga to be independent.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a wrapper function for `API` calls. Like this:

```js
// `apiRequest` dispatches `anotherAction` and calls given `apiCall` 
function* apiRequest(apiCall, ...args) {
  yield put(anotherAction())
  yield call(apiCall, ...arg)
}

export function* login({ payload }) {
  try {
    const resp = yield apiRequest(API.post, 'api/1/login', {
      email: payload.email,
      password: payload.password,
    })

    yield put(AuthActions.loginSuccess(resp.token))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(AuthActions.loginError(error))
  }
}
```